# Get the error code 500 when I upload a file size > 1MB to S3 Bucket (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get the error message when I want to upload a file size > 1MB to S3 Bucket in my company's network:
(If file size < 1MB, upload file working fine)

```
500: null
    at Request.extractError (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:711:35)
    at Request.callListeners (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at ...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (...\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 500,
  region: null,
  time: 2022-11-22T09:07:55.279Z,
  requestId: null,
  extendedRequestId: undefined,
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 500,
  retryable: true
}
```

And I found this error is simlar to this issue (https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1410),
but I still get the same error after I try to set s3ForcePathStyle to true while creating s3 object.

Here is my code:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', s3ForcePathStyle: true});
let result = await s3.upload( {Bucket: bucket_name, Key: file_path, Body: request.files.buffer}).promise();
// using upload and putObject api return same error
console.log(result);
```

But if I run the code in my home, there is no error, and file upload succeed.

In my code, I set the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED diabled to avoid ssl certificate problem, but still not working

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;
```

I also try to use AWS CLI CMD (aws s3api put-object ...) in my company, upload the file size > 1MB is working fine!!

I don't understand why I cannot using node.js code to upload the file size > 1MB in my company, doesn't AWS CLI and npm aws-sdk library using same protocol?

I guess this error maybe related to my company's environment, but AWS CLI is working fine. So, I think it probably could be fixed the problem in my code, hopping someone can help, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I try to set enpoint and remove s3ForcePathStyle while careting s3 object.

It's working now!

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', endpoint: 's3.amazonaws.com'});
```

But I still don't know why?